# graph3 strings didn't render properly with asymptote

Tags: asymptote

When I try to project a string over a plane some symbols like "O" are filled

```
import three;
path[] Oletter=texpath("O");
path3 Oletter3D = path3(Oletter[0],XYplane);
draw(surface(Oletter3D));
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `label` command is available in 3D as well:

```
import three;
size3(5cm);
label(XY()*"O",(0,0,0));
```

In your code you only use the outer curve of the symbol and it gets filled. An alternative is

```
import three;
surface s = surface(texpath("O"));
size3(5cm);
draw(s,blue);
```